# Running a Visual Studio macro from within a Unit Test

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, macros

Is it possible to trigger a macro from within a unit test and get back it's returned value? The macro checks the integrity of certain solution files accessible from the DTE. Using the DTE from within the Unit Test is not a good idea.

Comment: I think you are a little confused. Unit Testing is for behavior of compiled code. It should be able to run without the sources being about. What exactly do you mean by "integrity"? Surely by the time you can compile the "unit test" you have ensured "integrity" by...um... compiling it.

Comment: @Aron: No I am not confused about the role of unit testing. Some checks need to be performed to verify that the solution is properly configured for production and a unit test is just a convenient way to ensure the same. Specially since the solution cannot be published until all unit tests have passed.

Comment: Sounds like your deployment process is very manual. Consider automating your deployment process rather than manually configuring the system then deploying. Alternatively, consider using the environment to configure the deployment (use DNS/subnetting to segregate your environments). See [rule 2 of the Joel Test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html).

Comment: @Aron: I intentionally omitted context and narrowed down the question. This need to access compile-time settings has nothing to do with our deployment process.

Comment: How would this ever work on a build server?

Comment: Again see Joel test number 2. Can you build in one step? F5 is not a deployment process.

Comment: Gentlemen, it is not meant to run on a build server. This is specifically to make my own life easier. Please read the question. I have NOT mentioned a deployment context anywhere. The question is about triggering a Visual Studio Macro from within a Unit Test, which implies being in the context of the IDE, but not the DTE (as is the case with add-ins).

Comment: Perhaps context would be helpful then. Otherwise I am just going to suggest you ensure the correct build settings by running MSBUILD from a BAT file.

Comment: @Aron: The context is rather simple. I have multiple devs submit code via TFS, which I review, correct and publish. This is a desktop application and there is no build server involved. There is one particular class from which hundreds of classes derive and before doing code review, I want to run some automated tests on not only the source code but the runtime types to ensure conformity. I want to have this test available to the devs via source control as well. So in this case, we are using unit testing functionality for non-black-box testing as well.

Comment: Related to my comment above, the end objective is to run this macro either as part of test runs (which is convenient) or as part of the build process (which slows the build down and is annoying).

Comment: explain "conformity". Could `CODE ANALYSIS` be what you are looking for?

Comment: @Aron: Correct. My scenario allows me take certain assumptions about the code since devs are given strict guidelines. An example would be, no class level fields are allowed in classes that derive from X. This can be determined by instantiating the type in a unit test but there are other scenarios where only the actual source code can give me hints on what to prioritize or reject.

Comment: You misunderstand. You should create your own [Custom Code Analysis Rule for FxCop](http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2010/01/06/custom-code-analysis-rules-in-vs2010-and-how-to-make-them-run-in-fxcop-and-vs2008-too/). FxCop can be run separately or as part of a build definition on a build server or whatever....

Comment: @Aron: I'll read up on it but have two quick questions: (1) Can such rules integrate with source control so they are specific to one solution? (2) Do these rules provide an execution context so that runtime type properties may be analyzed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30376/discussion-between-aron-and-raheel-khan)